# How "Ask Question" links could be improved in SE sites?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, stack-exchange

I recently had to ask a question in StackOverflow, but I found difficult to find the ask question button. I suppose that asking a question is the main action an user will do in SE forums, and is difficult to find in some sites (SO, Programmers, Super User)

[image: Stack overflow buttons]

After noticing how difficult was to find the link (had to use browser search), I checked in other SE sites and found that they have external consistency (buttons are located top right), but for an user that is not familiarized with this pattern, it could be difficult to find the button.

How can this be improved? I found easier to find the button in http://ux.stackexchange.com and http://travel.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn't this a question to ask on the Meta.UX site?

Comment: @BennySkogberg No, it should go on Meta.Stack Overflow !

Comment: Migrated here because it's not specific to UX.SE (in fact it's not really an issue on UX.SE), nor to any one SE site.

Answer (score 5):

I find it a little humorous that we don't have this problem here on UX.SE. Only the Ask Question is a button. Everything else has been styled as a link.

We normally call this primary vs secondary actions. And typically we place more visual emphasis on the primary action to make it stand out. Using button vs link is one approach. Another approach would be to just use color. Assigning the more important primary action "Ask Question" with a color that contrasts with the other gray buttons.